# How to detect a basic audio signal into a much bigger one (mpg123 output signal)

Tags: audio, mp3, fftw, pcm, dft

I am new to signal processing and I don't really understand the basics (and more). Sorry in advance for any mistake into my understanding so far.

I am writing C code to detect a basic signal (18Hz simple sinusoid 2 sec duration, generating it using Audacity is pretty simple) into a much bigger mp3 file. I read the mp3 file and copy it until I match the sound signal.

The signal to match is { 1st channel: 18Hz sin. signal , 2nd channel: nothing/doesn't matter). 
To match the sound, I am calculating the frequency of the mp3 until I find a good percentage of 18Hz freq. during ~ 2 sec. As this frequency is not very common, I don't have to match it very precisely.

I used mpg123 to convert my file, I fill the buffers with what it returns. I initialised it to convert the mp3 to Mono RAW audio:
init:

```
int ret;
const long *rates;
size_t rate_count, i;
mpg123_rates(&rates, &rate_count);
mpg123_handle *m = mpg123_new(NULL, &ret);
mpg123_format_none(m);
for(i=0; i<rate_count; ++i)
    mpg123_format(m, rates[i], MPG123_MONO, MPG123_ENC_SIGNED_32);

if(m == NULL)
{
    //err
} else {
    mpg123_open_feed(m);
}
```

(...)

```
unsigned char out[8*MAX_MP3_BUF_SIZE];
ret = mpg123_decode(m, buf->data, buf->size, out, 8*MAX_MP3_BUF_SIZE, &size);
```

`(...)

```
unsigned char out[8*MAX_MP3_BUF_SIZE];
ret = mpg123_decode(m, buf->data, buf->size, out, 8*MAX_MP3_BUF_SIZE, &size);
```

(...) `

But I have to idea how to get the resulting buffer to calculate the FFT to get the frequency.

```
//FREQ Calculation with libfftw3
int transform_size = MAX_MP3_BUF_SIZE * 2;
fftw_complex *fftout = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * transform_size);
fftw_complex *fftin = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * transform_size);
fftw_plan p = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(transform_size, fftin, fftout, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
```

I can get a good RAW Audio (PCM ?) into a buffer (if I write it, it can be read and converted into wave with sox:
sox --magic -r 44100 -e signed -b 32 -c 1 rps.raw rps.wav

Any help is appreciated. My knowledge of signal processing is poor, I am not even sure of what to do with the FFT to get the frequency of the signal. Code is just fyi, it is contained into a much bigger project (for which a simple grep is not an option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use MP3 for this.  There's a good chance your 18 Hz will disappear or at least become distorted.  18 Hz is will below audible.  MP3 and other lossy algorithms use a variety of techniques to remove sounds that we're not going to hear.

Assuming PCM, since you only need one frequency band, consider using the [Goertzel algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm).  This is more efficient than FFT/DFT for your use case.

Comment: mp3 is a prerequisite. Thanks a lot for your input, I managed calculating the FFT, and I'm working on normalizing results and put them into buckets. The Goertzel algorithm gives me a single result, easier to manage and it seems to be working for small files I generated. Let me see how it performs for my 20kb buffers...

Comment: Hey Brad, Thanks a lot! I managed to getting what I want, Goertzel algorithm is far simpler than FFT ! , and I could decode mpg123 output which is a simple raw PCM buffer. I'll post the code soon.